# How to check whether a query string of type nullable int is invalid?

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to check whether users navigate with

- an invalid query string `\earth\xyz` or
- a valid query string `\earth\12` or
- a valid query string `\earth`.

The following I can only check the last two. How to check the first one?

```
<h3>Earth</h3>
@page "/earth"
@page "/earth/{id:int}"


@if(ID==null)
{
   <h1>Null</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>@ID</h1>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check that that way (or rather have have it indicated otherwise), simply because with url like `\earth\xyz`, the page is never hit at all; that is, the page is never rendered.

When the Router component does not find a match for the requested route, it displays
a `LayoutView` component with the text `<p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>`

Your page is never hit...

Here's the markup in App.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
       
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. So what is the recommended way to solve this issue?

Comment: What issue? There's no issue here...The user has simply typed a wrong url. Ordinarily web sites display a page with large image, big oops, and a link to the home page. If you insist, you may create code to verify if the url typed contains the literal earth, as for instance, \earth\xyz, and either automatically redirect the user to the earth page, or provide him a link to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lack of support regarding this in Blazor.

An alternative way of doing this is to change the id to string and manually parse it to `int` using [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) as @Eliezer mentioned.

Based on your three conditions:

- if the `TryParse` succeeds, that means the URL is valid and has an int parameter in it
- if the parsing fails and the `string ID` is null or empty that means the URL is valid
- if the parsing fails "and" the `string ID` is not null or empty, that means the URL is invalid.